# JPA - Querying Many-To-Many from Embeddable using Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have the following class mapping (only relevant pieces included, in reality mapping is done on getters, not attributes):

```
@Entity
class Item {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
class RootEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Emb relation;
}

@Embeddable
class Emb {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<Item> items;
}
```

I am trying to fetch all `Item`s, that belong to a particular `RootEntity`. The following JPQL query works as expected:

```
SELECT i FROM RootEntity r LEFT JOIN r.relation.items i WHERE r.id = :id
```

However, the following criteria query does not:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Item> query = cb.createQuery(Item.class);
Root<RootEntity> root = query.from(RootEntity.class);

query = query.select(root.join(RootEntity_.relation).join(Emb_.items, JoinType.LEFT));

Predicate p = cb.equal(root.get(RootEntity_.id), wantedId);
query = query.where(p);

return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

The generated SQL contains all `Item`'s columns with generated alias for the `Item` table, but the `FROM` part of the query contains only the `RootEntity` table, without the required join with `Item`, therefore the query fails.

I tested the criteria query on many-to-many mapping without the embeddable entity in-between and it works.

So, the question is - am I doing something wrong in respect to working with embeddable entities, or is this a bug?

Spring Data version: 1.8.2.RELEASE
Hibernate version: 4.3.6.Final
Underlying RDBMS: MySQL